# нужно сделать генератор автомобильных номеров в таком формате: X000XX в php

Tags: php

X-буквы (A, B), O-чифры в раене (000.. 999)
по формату ук выше но через с помощью конструкции for или while
X — это серия, тут может быть указана любая буква, имеющая аналог в кириллическом и латинском алфавите, а 000 — номер, он может принимать любые значения от 000 до 999. В нашем случае серия ограничена комбинациями A и B.
цикл for получается сделать один блок с серией а сам номер нет:

```
    <?php
$length=['A','B'];
$vall=rand(000.. 999);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $c .= $arr[random_int(0, count($arr) - 1)];
    return $c;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $vall; $i++) {
        $d .= $arv[random_int(0, count($arr) - 1)];
    return $d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пишите "через с помощью конструкции for или while", но почему тогда решить пытаетесь через с помощью SE?

Comment: попробавать написать рабочий генератор авто номеров через php с помощью конструкции for или while

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь хватит разума доделать под свои нужды, алгоритм выглядит вот так.

```
<?php
$num = range(0, 26*100-1); // 26 букв, 100 цифр (-1 перегрузка)
$num = array_map(function($el) {
    $chr = chr(intval($el / 100) + ord('A')); // для каждой 100й цифры, +1 буква
    $num = ($el % 100); // остаток от деления = чистые цифры
    return sprintf("%s-%02d", $chr, $num); // форматирование нулей
}, $num);
echo join("\n", $num);
```

Вывод

```
A-00
A-01
A-02
A-03
A-04
...
A-98
A-99
B-00
B-01
...
Z-96
Z-97
Z-98
Z-99
```

**Добавлено чуток спустя.**

Альтернативный и более ламерский способ.

```
<?php
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $a) {
    for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
        printf("%s-%02d\n", $a, $i);
    }
}
```

Comment: серия только А и Б, номера от 000 до 999. Ваш более "ламерский способ" на порядок более читаемый и понятный чем "гуру".